# name headers of all dimensions in an array (dim>2)

Tags: r, matrix, multidimensional-array, row, col

I would like to name the "levels" or "sections" or "layers" of a 3-dimensional array!

---

Is there a way to do this? To clarify: With levels mean the rows of a 3d matrix, when rotated  in the 2nd dimension. I found a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23427390/r-assigning-headers-to-an-three-dimentional-array/23427582#234275), which nevertheless doesn't cover this specific aspect.
Thanks for the answer @Spacedman. Anyway, what I want to have is an additional header for the third dimension:

```
numb.x <- sample(99, 80)
my.array <- array(numb.x, dim = c(5,4,3), dimnames = c("row","col","lev"))
rownames(my.array)<-c("ri","rj","rk","rl","rm")
colnames(my.array)<-c("cn","cm","co","cp")
my.array[,,1]
my.array[,1,]
```

So, how can I get headers for the last section of the array (previous line of code)using a vector of names as provided below?

```
levs <- c("lx","ly","lz")
```

Comment: Just try `my.array <- array(numb.x, dim = c(5,4,3), dimnames=list(c("ri","rj","rk","rl","rm"),c("cn","cm","co","cp"),c("lx","ly","lz")))`. The `dimnames` argument must be fed with a `list` and each element are the names of the corresponding dimension.

Comment: Thank you @nicola - you made my day! Would you mind to post this as an answer?